# datetimepicker bootstrap data bind not working

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I was working on datetimepicker (taken from https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) and wanted to store the value of the date inside ng-model. However, the date is not stored even we did the usual data-binding.

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 input-group date" id="equipList">
         <label for="date">Selection of Year</label>
         <input type="text" id="datetimepicker11" class="form-control" placeholder="Year" data-ng-model="yearFilter"/>
      </div>

        {{yearFilter}}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#datetimepicker11').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'YYYY'
            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this to solve it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#datetimepicker11').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'YYYY'
            });

        $("#datetimepicker11").on("dp.change", function() {

        $scope.yearFilter = $("#datetimepicker11").val();

    });
});
```